# Can I create an openssl key for a server from a different host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tomcat, openssl

I have two EC2 instances with an ALB and I need an SSL certificate for Tomcat.  I don't have shell access to the EC2 instances, I can only work them via Ansible.  I have to generate a cert request but I need a key to do that.
Can I generate a key on my own machine and use that to request the cert?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you generate the key at all, as longs as you can securely transfer and install your key on the target server  together with the certificate once the CSR has been processed. -

Answer (score 2):

Yes, technically the CSR request can be signed with any key anywhere, but once the signed certificate is generated you will need to use the same key you have used for the CSR request.

So in other words, you will need to transfer the key somehow to the servers so Tomcat can use the certificate along with the key.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with SSL/TLS you have to take in consideration the security aspect of your actions.

Yes technically it is possible to generate the key and copy it to another machine. But my advice is to generate and keep the key only on the destination server, and never copy the key somewhere else.

It is also possible to have 2 different certificate-and-key pairs at the same time. this has the advantage that if one site is compromised, you can still use the other machine and certificate+key that is not yet compromised.